# Array stays empty when using Array.push in promise

Tags: arrays, typescript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to collect all the documents from a specific file and transform them into a Sendgrid attachment object with a content and filename property.

Step 1 and 2 are working. After step 2 I have an array of objects with some document data like the file name, type, storage URL etc.

In step 3 I want to fetch the actual file based on the storage URL and create a Sendgrid attachment object. It requires `content` and `filename` as properties.

However, with my current code, the attachments array stays empty when I'm logging the variable.

My code:

```
export const onStatusChanged = functions.database.ref(`files/{fileID}/general/status`).onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    const prevStatus = change.before.val();
    const currentStatus = change.after.val();

    if (prevStatus === currentStatus) return null;

    if (currentStatus === 'email') {
        // 1. Get file data
        const snapshot = await change.after.ref.parent.parent.once('value');
        const file = snapshot.val();

        // 2. Get documents
        const documents = getDocuments(file.documents);
        console.log(documents);

        // 3. Create attachments
        const attachments = [];

        documents.forEach(document => {
            axios.get(document.url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).then(image => {
                attachments.push({ content: Buffer.from(image.data).toString('base64'), filename: document.name });
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
        });

        console.log(attachments) // []

        // 4. Create email object

        // 5. Send email
    }

    return null;
})
```

I thought by using a promise my code is synchronous?

EDIT: first I had this code

```
    // 3. Create attachments
    const attachments = documents.map(document => {
        const image = await axios.get(document.url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
        return attachments.push({ content: Buffer.from(image.data).toString('base64'), filename: document.name });
    })

    console.log(attachments) // [ Promise { <pending> } ]
```

Comment: "I thought by using a promise my code is synchronous?" -> as you discovered, that's not the case. There are different ways to sequentialize async code -- we used to do `async.waterfall` and maybe this is still done. You might be thinking about using `await`. This new keyword makes async code _look_ synchronous, though it is still definitely async. Have you tried `await` in your `forEach`?

Comment: @RayToal: First I did use await with a `map()` function. Added this code

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand the use of promises specifically with Cloud Functions. With Cloud Functions background triggers, you are obliged to return a promise that resolves when all the async work is fully complete, else the work will be shut down. Right now you are returning null, which isn't correct.

Also, `attachements` doesn't seem to be accumulating promises.  It's accumulating other objects that are not useful for async programming.

Read more in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Comment: I will check the documentation and come back afterward. Thanks for the url.

Comment: Changed the code to async/await and wrapped the loop in `Promise.all()`.
At the end of the if-condition (step 5) I will return a promise when sending the actual email.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the code back to async/await and added `Promise.all()`. It's working like I want now.

The code:

```
    const attachments = await Promise.all(documents.map(async document => {
        const image = await axios.get(document.url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
        return { content: Buffer.from(image.data).toString('base64'), filename: document.name };
    }));
```